# Perform segue programmatically

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I am just jacking  around with table views. I need to assign a segue programaticAlly. My code is

```
[self preformSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:tableview];
```

It says an ARC issue which is:

> No visible interface for 'MasterViewController' declares selector       'preformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:

Comment: post `MasterViewController.h`

Comment: I can't. I am using mobile. I am realizing I do not have -(void)preformSegueWithIdentfier.

Comment: Is your `MasterViewController` a subclass of `UIViewController`?

Comment: Oh nvm. Yes. It was generated by xcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `preformSegueWithIdentifier` with `performSegueWithIdentifier`.